# TFS API Query Merges between branches

Tags: c#, api, tfs, merge

I'm trying to use TFS API to query the merges between two branches. I have the TFS path of both branches i.e.

```
$/teamprojects/branchA/ (parent branch)
$/teamprojects/branchB/ (child branch)
```

I need an efficient query to get something like:
**branchB** merged into **branchA** at 12/12/2013 23:43. Last check-in before the merge in **branchB** was 123456 and it's time stamp is 12/12/2013 20:20.

I'm trying to use QueryMerges:

```
merges = (IEnumerable<ChangesetMerge>)_versionControl.QueryMerges(branch.Path, VersionSpec.Latest, child.Path, VersionSpec.Latest, dateFrom, dateTo, RecursionType.Full);
```

But I get a lot of ChangesetMerges (some of them with the same time stamp) and the query itself is extremely slow.

Comment: The full recursion looks for all merges at the file level, I suspect it's enough to use RecursionType.None

Comment: RecursionType.None doesn't return anything even though RecursionType.Full does. How can this happen?